# Spring security custom authentication for REST services

Tags: rest, spring-security

I have a third-party REST service that I need to integrate with Spring security.

The REST service send the login and password as part of the JSON message, like this:

```
{
    "user":"foo",
    "pwd":"bar",
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

I think that I need to do a custom-filter to handle the JSON message and login into the application, but I'm lost with the configuration.

Which interface do I need to implement in this custom-filter?

Any sample of a similar scenario?

Comment: I've done it, but it's not straightforward. Do you allow anonymous access? Do you want to handle logouts? What should you return in case of: 0. lack of authentication 1. logout success 2. login success 3. login failure? Should output be in JSON? What in case an exception is thrown - should it be translated?